# What is the Difference between "Contrib Module" and "Custom Module"?

Tags: php, drupal, migration, drupal-7, drupal-8

In Drupal CMS, what I understand is that version 8 is different in terms of coding to version 7. If I write code myself then I do not have to use **Contribute Module**?

So for upgrading self written code from version 7 to version 8, I need to use **Custom Module**?  Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Yes, totally wrong. Contrib = hosted on drupal.org, custom = written yourself or hosted somewhere else. That's not different between any Drupal core version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contributed module is a module, which was made by the community and then released on drupal.org so others can use them.

A custom module, is a module, which you write yourself for your own project(s).

Speaking of that, a custom module can also become a contributed module.

**To answer your question:** It does not really matter in what folder you put it in. It just is more structured/cleaner if you put your own modules inside the *custom* and modules from other people in *contributed*.